# matching with single character > or lines that start with >\s

Tags: regular-expression, global-command

I want to delete any lines that either match `^>$` or `>\s`

I have something like this, but this doesn't work:`nnoremap dq :.,$g/^>[\s$]/d<CR>`

Here's a small sample where it should delete the first 3 lines but not the last two (if we are currently at the top line of course):

```
>
>
> delete up to here

>butnotthis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use `\|` to specify two patterns: `%g/^>$\|^>\s/d`

Comment: Or `:global/^>\($|\s\)/delete` (note that `:%` is the default for `:global`)

Comment: extremely weird, but it seems to me, that if I type it in manually it works, if I put it in an `nmap` it complains that `Pattern not found: ^>$|^>\s` (for @D.BenKnoble's variant as well, but with of course a slightly different pattern)

Comment: @fbence in a mapping, `\|` is used to escape a `|` that would other end the map command start a new one (also written `<bar>`). So you can write `:nnoremap ??? :global/^>\($\<bar>\s\)/delete<CR>` or use `\v` with `:nnoremap ??? :global/\v^>($<bar>\s)/delete<CR>`. If you put it in a function and call the function from a mapping, you won't have this trouble.

Comment: ah, ok, thanks!